# How can I show a progress or loading bar while each data upload to server and a success message when through

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, axios, try-catch

Please I am trying to improve this code to show a progress or loading bar while sending individual answer to the server. Sometimes there may be up to 100 answers being sent that is 100 post request to the server. In this my current approach the user will receive 100 success message which can be very confusing and from experience it can take up to 3 minutes for the task to complete.

Is there a way for me to show a progress or loading bar while each answer payload upload to the server and a success message when the whole task is complete?

```
export const uploadAnswers = async (type) => {

    getOfflineSavedAnswers(type).then(async answers => {
        if (answers && answers.length > 0) {
            try {
                for (const answer of answers) {
                    try {
                        await axios.post('/route/question/create-answer', answer)
                        .then(res => {
                            delAnswers()
                            ts(`Answers successfully submitted!`);
                        })
                        .catch(err => {
                            console.error(err);
                            te(`Answers submission failed!`)
                        });
                    } catch (error) {
                        te(`Answers submission failed!`)
                    }
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
                te(`Answers submission failed!`)
            }
        }

    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use one extra state and set it initial value false. And when your answer starts uploading this state is set true. At this period you can show progress bar as shown below. when all answers are uploaded this state is set false due to which progress bar will be hidden
const [sucess, setSucess] = useState(false)
export const uploadAnswers = async (type) => {

```
    getOfflineSavedAnswers(type).then(async answers => {
        if (answers && answers.length > 0) {
            try {
                for (const answer of answers) {
                    try {
                        await axios.post('/route/question/create-answer',answer)
                        .then(res => {
                            delAnswers()
                            setSucess(true)
                            ts(`Answers successfully submitted!`);
                        })
                        .catch(err => {
                            console.error(err);
                            
                        });
                    } catch (error) {
                        te(`Answers submission failed!`)
                    }
                }
                if(sucess){
                    ts(`Answers successfully submitted!`);
                }
                setSucess(false)
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
                te(`Answers submission failed!`)
            }
        }

    });
};
return(
  {sucess? 'uploadin ans...' : null} //instead of this you can add 
                                                      // progress/loading 
)
```

Comment: I am having an issue. The file where ```uploadAnswers``` is exported from is not a functional component. In fact I have multiple instances of similar functions exported as const from the file. I am exploring how to work around it.